# A namespace declaration cannot be located prior to a class or function with which it is merged

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have react app based on [react-redux-typescript-boilerplate](https://github.com/rokoroku/react-redux-typescript-boilerplate) I've created this file:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import { RootState } from 'app/reducers';

export namespace LasarTitle {
  export interface Props {
    title: string;
    loading: boolean;
  };
};

@connect(
  (state: RootState): LasarTitle.Props => {
    return { title: state.title, loading: state.loading };
  },
  () => { }
)
export class LasarTitle extends React.Component<LasarTitle.Props> {
  static defaultProps: Partial<LasarTitle.Props> = {
    title: ''
  };
  constructor(props: LasarTitle.Props, context?: any) {
    super(props, context);
  }
  render() {
    const title = this.props.loading ? 'loading...' : this.props.title;
    return (
      <div>
        <input readOnly={true} value={title} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

which is exactly the same as [containers/App/index.tsx](https://github.com/rokoroku/react-redux-typescript-boilerplate/blob/master/src/app/containers/App/index.tsx) it have namespace and connect on component with the same name.

What's wrong with my code? I've didn't notice any typos or errors. What's the difference between my code and boilerplate?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error is pretty explicit. You just need to move the namespace declaration after the class.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import { RootState } from 'app/reducers';


@connect(
  (state: RootState): LasarTitle.Props => {
    return { title: state.title, loading: state.loading };
  },
  () => { }
)
export class LasarTitle extends React.Component<LasarTitle.Props> {
  static defaultProps: Partial<LasarTitle.Props> = {
    title: ''
  };
  constructor(props: LasarTitle.Props, context?: any) {
    super(props, context);
  }
  render() {
    const title = this.props.loading ? 'loading...' : this.props.title;
    return (
      <div>
        <input readOnly={true} value={title} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export namespace LasarTitle {
  export interface Props {
    title: string;
    loading: boolean;
  };
}
```

Since the namespace and the class have the same name, they will be merged. One of the things merging will do is that there will be only one object at runtime representing the combined class-namespace. For reason of implementation such a merger requires that the class object be created first and then namespace members be added to it.

**Edit**

If your namespace only contains types this rule will not be applied, if it contains code (such as function or variable declarations) the rule will apply. The boiler-plate works because it contains no code. While not obvious, your namespace does contain code, the `;` at the end of the interface will be transpiled to empty JS statements, and thus the rule is enforced.

The better solution would be to remove the `;`

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import { RootState } from 'app/reducers';

export namespace LasarTitle {
  export interface Props {
    title: string;
    loading: boolean;
  }
};

@connect(
  (state: RootState): LasarTitle.Props => {
    return { title: state.title, loading: state.loading };
  },
  () => { }
)
export class LasarTitle extends React.Component<LasarTitle.Props> {
  static defaultProps: Partial<LasarTitle.Props> = {
    title: ''
  };
  constructor(props: LasarTitle.Props, context?: any) {
    super(props, context);
  }
  render() {
    const title = this.props.loading ? 'loading...' : this.props.title;
    return (
      <div>
        <input readOnly={true} value={title} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you know why the example file in boilerplate is working without problem even that namespace is first? Do you see the difference between my code and boilerplate?

Comment: @jcubic took me a while to find the differenc, updated the answer

Comment: Wow, big props, would never be able to figure out this on my own.

Comment: Your edit regarding the fact that the rule will not be enforced if the namespace contains only types is very clarifying. But what about enums? The rule seems to be enforced if my interface contains an enum. But I thought an enum is a (kind of a) type as well. Why is the rule enforced when the namespace contains enums?

Comment: @BartHofland  enums are both a type and a runtime object. So js is emitted for them.

Comment: Yes, of course. You are absolutely right. I have played around with it for a little while and looked at the generated JavaScript, and it makes sense to me now. Thank you. :)